# Putting a bike on/off side stand, did I take the side stand off?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

[image]

So is it :

> I put the bike on the side stand.
>
> I put the bike off the side stand.

Do these sentences sound natural?

And my mom asked me:

> Did I take the side stand off?

Do these sentences sound natural? If not then what sounds natural?

Comment: Actually, what your mom asked was probably *Did **you** take the side stand off?* But presumably she's not a native speaker anyway - if ***I*** were your mom I'd more likely ask *Is it on the side stand?* (or "your bike" rather than "it" if that wasn't contextually obvious).

Comment: Put [on] and take [off] are used for opposing actions. Put on a hat; take it off again. Put a bike on its stand; take a bike off its stand.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, that component of a two-wheeled vehicle is called the **kickstand** (I suppose because you *kick* it into position).  There are various mechanisms for this purpose, but all are generally called the same thing.  You can *take off* or *remove* a kickstand, but that means physically separating it from the vehicle.

If you are *parking* the vehicle, then I suppose you can say something like:

> **Lean/Rest** the bike on its kickstand.

or

> **Put down** the kickstand and **lean/rest** the bike on that.

But both of these are really too much explanation.  Normally you would just say:

> **Park** your bike.

Yes, there are various ways to do this, but most of the time it doesn't matter.  Most people know how to park their own bikes, or only care that it is parked and not *how* you parked it.

Comment: And what about asking a person whether you had pulled it up? That is "opposite of put down".

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish you would **retract** or perhaps **raise** the side stand (the BrE term for kick stand).

Comment: And what about "put up"? "Did you put up the kickstand?"

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish   Sure, "raise", "lift", "put up", "kick up", "take [the bike] off", or perhaps whatever else makes sense.  It's not something people mention, though, because it's such a trivial maneuver.